# How to create tags? Docpad

Tags: tags, docpad

How can I make the tags?
For example http://dogfeet.github.io
Are there other examples?

I'm add docpad-plugin-tagging but, Digital tags are not displayed alttest.herokuapp.com/tags/404.html :(

and how to create tags to one page alttest.herokuapp.com/posts/2013/2013-03-24_car_driving? Only Tags page, not all

my repo https://github.com/npofopr/_altyncev_test

Answer (score 0):

You can add tags as an array or Comma Separated Value inside your meta data:

```
----
title: "My post title"
tags: "tag1 tag2 tag3"
----
```

Then access the tags for the current document via:

```
@document.tags
```

Comment: Yes. But it will not be referred.
I want to make a tag with links